# why comparative operation on set return False?

Tags: python

I have problem with this code. i can't understand why this happened?
i am going to compare two set by >=< but all output are False !

```
>>> x=set([1,2,3])
>>> y=set([3])
>>> x<y
False
>>> x>y
False
>>> x==y
False
```

actually I want to know why it return False .

Comment: [Comparisons are implemented in an interesting way for sets.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects). `<=` means "issubset", for example.

Comment: Uh, now no repro, using ipython, python 2.7, on Ubuntu mostly 14.04

Comment: No repro is python 3.4 in Windows 7 either.

Comment: You need to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

Comment: Well of course the example in your image returns false. {2} is not a subset of {1}, and {1} is not a subset of {2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a slight mistake:

```
>>> x = {1,2,3}
>>> y = {3}
>>> x > y
True
>>> x < y
False
>>> x == y
False
```

You tested `x < y` and `y > x` which gave you the same result. Now you can see that `x > y`.

---

However, there are sets for which all three comparisons are actually `False`:

```
>>> x = {1,2,3}
>>> y = {1,2,4}
>>> x > y
False
>>> x < y
False
>>> x == y
False
```

and this is due to the implementation of `<=>` for sets, which compares sets via subset logic (`x < y` asks if `x` is a *strict* subset of `y`).

Answer (score 0):

You did `x<y` and `y>x`. These are the same. Probably you mean to do `x<y` and `y<x`.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) -

> In addition, both Set and ImmutableSet support set to set comparisons. Two sets are equal if and only if every element of each set is contained in the other (each is a subset of the other). A set is less than another set if and only if the first set is a proper subset of the second set (is a subset, but is not equal). A set is greater than another set if and only if the first set is a proper superset of the second set (is a superset, but is not equal).

So `y` is less than `x` . If you do `y < x` you will get true -

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> y = set([3])
>>> x < y
False
>>> y < x
True
```

Your comparisons , were - `x < y` (x less than y , which is false) , `y > x` (y greather than x , which is same as previous one) , again false. And `x == y` which is also false (since both sets do not have equal elements).

---

Based on the screenshot you added, seems like x is `{1}` and y is `{2}` .

You can check the snippet from documentation I added above, in set , less than returns true only if the set on the left side is a subset of the set on the right side, in your case, both x and y are not subsets of each other, hence x is not less than y , and y is not less than y and they are not equal.

Example -

```
>>> x = {1}
>>> y = {2}
>>> x < y
False
>>> y < x
False
```

Comment: `x > y` is coming `True` for me , which version are you using?

Comment: @user3623419 Please check my latest update and the snippet from documentation I added.

Answer (score 0):

```
x<y
```

is the same as

```
y>x
```

and sets are not the same sets so `x == y` gives False too.

Comment: yes u are right . I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The only route to altering the way built-in containers check equality is to make them contain as values, instead of the "originals", wrapped values (wrapped in a class that overrides `__eq__` and `__ne__`). This is if you need to alter the way the containers themselves use equality checking, e.g. for the purpose of the in operator where the right-hand side operand is a list -- as well as in containers' method such as their own `__eq__` (`type(x).__eq__(y)` is the typical way Python will perform internally what you code as `x == y`).

If what you're talking about is performing your own equality checks (without altering the checks performed internally by the containers themselves), then the only way is to change every `cont1 == cont2` into (e.g.) `same(cont1, cont2, value_same)` where value_same is a function accepting two values and returning `True` or `False` like `==` would. That's probably too invasive WRT the criterion you specify.

If you can change the container themselves (i.e., the number of places where container objects are created is much smaller than the number of places where two containers are checked for equality), then using a container subclass which overrides `__eq__` is best.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the results in your question

```
>>> x=set([1,2,3])
>>> y=set([3])
>>> x<y
False
>>> x>y
True
>>> x==y
False
```

If there is a version of Python that returns `False` for `x>y` it is a bug in the Python implementation.

I suspect you didn't copy and paste from your console, and retyped what you *think* it said.